# Is there a standard for utility data API similar banking Open Banking

Tags: api, standards

My project relies on obtaining customer account/bill data from their utilities in the UK e.g. Sky, British Gas, BT etc. I have seen apps that do this and I am wondering if there is a standard way of interacting with this data like there is in banking using Open Banking.

I may be wrong but I can't imagine that all these sites will be screen scraping all the utility websites as it opens the door to many bugs as the sites update their UI. It also means that every user is giving these applications access to their whole account, and not just a subset of readonly data.

Answer (score 0):

Carl,

Don't believe there is a standardized API/approach to access data from utility providers in the UK.

In Australia, that is exactly what we are attempting to do with Consumer Data Right (CDR). The idea is to get various sectors (starting with Banks and then moving on to Energy and then to Telco and possibly others) to expose APIs which can be used by TPPs to get access to consumer data and provide innovative services.

May be UK and other countries will open up other sectors besides Banking soon!